# Canonical and microcanonical ensemble

Tags: statistical-mechanics, definition

What does one mean by **canonical** and **micro canonical ensemble** in statistical mechanics? Can one elaborate on this in a very simple way with examples? Pardon me, if it is a very simple thing; I am a math student.

Comment: Did you check Wikipedia? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_ensemble http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcanonical_ensemble

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Microcanonical ensemble means an isolated system with defined energy. The system may be found only in microscopic state with the adequate energy, with equal probability.

Canonical ensemble means a system attached to the "temperature reservoir", which may supply/take infinite amount of energy. The system may be found in any microscopic state, with probability proportional to the Boltzmann factor.

Comment: It's worth stressing the equivalence between this answer and @user1504's (underappreciated) answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the 'microcanonical ensemble', you describe the macroscopic state of a system by giving a probability measure on the space of microscopic states.  This probability measure maximizes entropy, subject to the constraint that the energy is constant.

In the 'canonical ensemble', you describe the macroscopic state of a system with a probability measure which maximizes entropy subject to the constraint the expectation value of the energy is constant.

Comment: In a microcanonical ensemble isn't it true that all microstates are equally probable and hence the probability distribution is just flat?

Comment: @user6818 yes this is true. and one can derive this from the principle of maximal entropy as it's suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical ensembles is the collection of a large number of essentially independent system having the some temperature. Volume and the some number of identical particles. The individual system of this ensembles are seperated by rigid impremeable and conducting walls.